# How can we display additional spaces using markdown?

Tags: discussion, markdown, whitespace

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6220514/revisions
>
> [How do I do a multi-line string in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220420/node-js-multi-line-string/6220514#6220514)

I tried to make these characters: `[var str = "Some \ ]` show as having a space at the end without the brackets involved, but was not able to. While that would be doable on

```
var str = "Some \
```

that syntax, it's hard to indicate there's a space after the slash.

SOOOO, without using another character (like a light mid dot) to indicate the space therein, is that possible with markdown?

For reference:

`var str = "Some \` //has a space

vs

`var str = "Some \` //does not have a space

Comment: If you actually put a space, there is one there (and it's selectable, etc.).  Markdown renders it inside a `<code>` tag which doesn't clobber spaces on rendering.  What would you propose?  It may just be incumbent upon the poster to indicate that spaces belong there.

Comment: @Daniel, see the new edit. I want the last two code lines to look differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to make it apparent that there's a space, you'll have to do more than put one, you'll have to emphasize it elsewhere anyway. Compare, visually:

`no space here \`
    `but there is a space here \`

(rendered with an unbreakable space, which is not a good idea when posting code since if you do copy-paste it it usually won't work). So you might as well use a visually distinct character, traditionally ␣:

`explicitly indicated space \␣` (note that `␣` means a space character)

There's a similar problem when you need to indicate a literal control character, which is less frequent but does happen occasionally:

`␛knew title␛\` (where `␛` means a literal escape character, i.e., press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd>)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by prepending the line with space characters, instead of using backticks.

The following line should end with 6 spaces

```
var str = "Some \
```

vs

`var str = "Some \` //does not have a space

But I'm not sure how to do this within a backtick code block.

Comment: The intent was to _avoid_ using "// has six spaces" at all. I don't guess I made the link out to the revisions page prominent enough to reference the original question. Also note that in my question, I purposefully showed that I knew that I could use the code block syntax. Note the 2756 rep on _meta_ ... I know this network pretty well.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your question.